How to put poem titles in header?
I am using the Verse package \usepackage{verse} which does a fine job formatting my poems. I have multiple poems in a document, so, multiple uses of \begin{verse} ... \end{verse}. Each poem has a title \poemtitle{Poem Title}. I would like that title to be in the header. Section 3.2.5 of the Verse package documentation strongly hints that this should be possible, but I guess I don't know enough latex to make it work. If I make a table of contents, the poem title goes there, so latex does have the needed title information stored somehow. The documentation mentions a \poemtitlemark that "would probably be changed by a pagestyle definition (like \sectionmark or \chaptermark)." I don't know how to use those commands. Using \fancyhead{\leftmark} and \fancyhead{\rightmark} give an empty header. Directly typing the title into the header (i.e. \fancyhead{Invictus} as below) works fine for one poem, but for multiple poems it would put that same title above them all.  How can I get the title into the header automatically? Thanks for your help.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{verse}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr} 
        \pagestyle{fancy}
        \fancyhf{}
        \fancyhead[L]{Invictus} %% poem title automatically here
        \fancyhead[R]{p.~\thepage}

\begin{document}

\begin{verse}

\poemtitle{Invictus}
by William Ernest Henley

Out of the night that covers me, \\
\vin Black as the pit from pole to pole, \\
I thank whatever gods may be \\
\vin For my unconquerable soul. \\!
\ldots

\end{verse}

\end{document}


As @John has told in his answer, you just need to redefine \poemtitlemark (see section 3.2.5 of the verse documentation for this command). But in opposite to his answer, I strongly recommend to use the mark mechanism of (La)TeX similar to the definition of \sectionmark or \chaptermark as shown in the fancyhdr documentation:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{verse}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr} 
        \pagestyle{fancy}
        \fancyhf{}
        \fancyhead[L]{\rightmark} %% poem title automatically here
        \fancyhead[R]{p.~\thepage}
\renewcommand{\poemtitlemark}[1]{\markright{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{verse}

\poemtitle{Invictus}
by William Ernest Henley

Out of the night that covers me, \\
\vin Black as the pit from pole to pole, \\
I thank whatever gods may be \\
\vin For my unconquerable soul. \\!
\ldots

\poemtitle{Test}

\end{verse}

\end{document}


or
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{verse}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr} 
        \pagestyle{fancy}
        \fancyhf{}
        \fancyhead[L]{\leftmark} %% poem title automatically here
        \fancyhead[R]{p.~\thepage}
\renewcommand{\poemtitlemark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{verse}

\poemtitle{Invictus}
by William Ernest Henley

Out of the night that covers me, \\
\vin Black as the pit from pole to pole, \\
I thank whatever gods may be \\
\vin For my unconquerable soul. \\!
\ldots

\poemtitle{Test}

\end{verse}

\end{document}


The difference of using \markright{…} and \rightmark or \markboth{…}{…} and \leftmark is which title is used, if there are more than one titles on the same page.
The usage of the mark mechanism is very important. Otherwise, if a \poemtitle results in a page break, the heading of the previous page can be wrong:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{verse}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr} 
        \pagestyle{fancy}
        \fancyhf{}
        \fancyhead[L]{\leftmark} %% poem title automatically here
        \fancyhead[R]{p.~\thepage}
\renewcommand{\poemtitlemark}[1]{\xdef\leftmark{#1}}% Don't do this!

\newcounter{mypoemline}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\dummypoem}[1][4]{%
  \setcounter{mypoemline}{0}%
  \@whilenum \value{mypoemline}<#1 \do{This is is dummy
    poem\\\stepcounter{mypoemline}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{verse}

\poemtitle{Invictus}
by William Ernest Henley

Out of the night that covers me, \\
\vin Black as the pit from pole to pole, \\
I thank whatever gods may be \\
\vin For my unconquerable soul. \\!
\ldots

\dummypoem[25]

\poemtitle{Test}

\dummypoem

\end{verse}

\end{document}


Because of a inconvenient placement of \poemtitlemark in verse, this can unfortunately also happen with the \markboth solution shown above. So I would recommend to use the \markright solution:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{verse}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr} 
        \pagestyle{fancy}
        \fancyhf{}
        \fancyhead[L]{\rightmark} %% poem title automatically here
        \fancyhead[R]{p.~\thepage}
\renewcommand{\poemtitlemark}[1]{\markright{#1}}

\newcounter{mypoemline}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\dummypoem}[1][4]{%
  \setcounter{mypoemline}{0}%
  \@whilenum \value{mypoemline}<#1 \do{This is is dummy
    poem\\\stepcounter{mypoemline}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{verse}

\poemtitle{Invictus}
by William Ernest Henley

Out of the night that covers me, \\
\vin Black as the pit from pole to pole, \\
I thank whatever gods may be \\
\vin For my unconquerable soul. \\!
\ldots

\dummypoem[25]

\poemtitle{Test}

\dummypoem

\end{verse}

\end{document}


If you want a table of contents or if you want the \markright solution, I would recommend to use a corrected order of commands in the definition of \@vsptitle. Otherwise a similar mistake in verse, adding:
\makeatletter
\def\@vsptitle[#1]#2{%
  \@nameuse{phantomsection}%
  \@vstypeptitle{#2}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{\poemtoc}{#1}%
  \poemtitlemark{#1}%
   \@afterheading
}
\makeatother

to the document preamble. Without this change, not only the page header of the second page, but also the page number of the second poem would be wrong in the following example:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{verse}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr} 
        \pagestyle{fancy}
        \fancyhf{}
        \fancyhead[L]{\leftmark} %% poem title automatically here
        \fancyhead[R]{p.~\thepage}
\renewcommand{\poemtitlemark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}

% Correction of the position of the toc entry and the mark:
\makeatletter
\def\@vsptitle[#1]#2{%
  \@nameuse{phantomsection}%
  \@vstypeptitle{#2}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{\poemtoc}{#1}%
  \poemtitlemark{#1}%
   \@afterheading
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{mypoemline}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\dummypoem}[1][4]{%
  \setcounter{mypoemline}{0}%
  \@whilenum \value{mypoemline}<#1 \do{This is is dummy
    poem\\\stepcounter{mypoemline}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\begin{verse}

\poemtitle{Invictus}
by William Ernest Henley

Out of the night that covers me, \\
\vin Black as the pit from pole to pole, \\
I thank whatever gods may be \\
\vin For my unconquerable soul. \\!
\ldots

\dummypoem[25]

\poemtitle{Test}

\dummypoem

\end{verse}

\end{document}



Fortunately, verse provides a hook for that.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{verse}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr} 
        \pagestyle{fancy}
        \fancyhf{}
        \fancyhead[L]{\leftmark} %% poem title automatically here
        \fancyhead[R]{p.~\thepage}
%\renewcommand{\poemtitlemark}[1]{\xdef\leftmark{#1}}% oops
\renewcommand{\poemtitlemark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\begin{document}

\begin{verse}

\poemtitle{Invictus}
by William Ernest Henley

Out of the night that covers me, \\
\vin Black as the pit from pole to pole, \\
I thank whatever gods may be \\
\vin For my unconquerable soul. \\!
\ldots

\end{verse}

\end{document}


This would result in incorrect page headers if \poemtitle results in a page break. See the example in my answer. You should always use the mark mechanism for running heads to avoid this.

Oops.  I was thinking that the mark mechanism wouldn't change the title until the next page, but that is only if you put two marks on the same page (e.g. \chaptermark and \sectionmark).

\chapter starts a new page before \chaptermark is used.
